# What were the names of the weapon manufacturers in France in the late 1700's

Tags: economy, france, weapons, napoleonic-wars, industrial-history

What were the names of the companies that manufactured hand weapons in France in the late 1700's and who were the most productive.

Comment: The largest weapons manufacturers would have been the state armories at Charleville, St. Etienne, Mauberge & Tulle. These manufactured the Model 1777 Infantry musket and the Model 1777 flintlock pistol which were the most common French infantry weapons of the revolutionary and Napoleonic period. However, there would have been a variety of other weapon manufacturers of various sizes making more bespoke weaponry.

Comment: I suspect that there were different manufacturers for different types of hand weapons - sword manufacture is different from gun manufacture. What kind of "hand weapon" are you looking for?

Comment: A very good question, sorry for my lack of clarity. I would like to know the answer to both.

Comment: most countries in this period France included, weapons manufacture was almost solely a government thing.